# Setting variables in Constructor using this

Tags: java, c++, constructor, field

So I am OK with java, but new to C++.  I am basically trying to make a Constructor for C++ with a parameter passed, and assign that value to the field for that object using `this`.  So here is what it would look like in java:

```
//Foo fields
    private int num;

//Foo Constructor
    public Foo(int num){
    this.num = num;
    }
```

How can I use `this` to set a variable like that in C++? Or is this not an option?  Thanks!!

Comment: i see. that works thanks! :) please post that as an answer, and would u mind clarifying why?

Comment: Note that although you can use a function parameter with the same name of a class member variable, it is not good practice in C++. Actually, class member variables should have some form of prefix or suffix (I like to use: f_num, the standard library uses num_, and many people used m_num under MS-Windows Visual Studio.) That way you can just write: `f_num = num;` since both variables have different names `this->...` is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this->num`, as in c++ this is a pointer, to access struct/class members via pointer you have to use `->` instead of `.` between variable and member name, here is from [manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)

```
expression  can be read as
*x          pointed by x
&x          address of x
x.y         member y of object x
x->y        member y of object pointed by x
```

Comment: You can also just use the class variable names:
`public Foo(int other){
    num = other;
    }`

Answer (score 3):

C++ has an even cleaner approach, called [constructor initializers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html). Instead of having lots of assignments, you can use this syntax:

```
public MyClass::MyClass(int num): someVar(num), someOtherVar(0) {
    // constructor here
}
```

If you really, really want to use `this`, remember that in C++ `this` is a pointer, so you have to use the pointer dereference operators, so either

```
this->num = num;
```

or

```
(*this).num = num;
```

Comment: Cool Thanks for the new info! Could I do ..."MyClass(int num): num(num){"... ?

Comment: @Evorlor Yes, you can!